# Break down on something

Tags: word-usage

In a novel, there was a line:
"And do we get 'wanted posters'? Leo said."Do we have bounties,like,broken down on a price list?"

So what does "break down on" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breakdown) gives this definition for **breakdown**

> NOUN
>   **3.1** An explanatory analysis, especially of statistics.
>   *a detailed cost breakdown*

What is meant is a list of wanted people, with their bounty values — like a price list.

There is a difference between **breakdown** and **break down**:

- The word **breakdown** is a noun.
- The phrase **break down** is a phrasal verb.

You asked about the phrase "break down on" but "on" is not part of that phrase, it is a preposition before "a price list".

The sentence shown with its phrasing is

> Do we have bounties, like, [broken down] [on a price list]?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Could you please explain more fully @Weather Vane? So it means something like: Do we have bounties, like, in simper terms (or broken down) on a price list?

Comment: There is not much context, but I suspect it is meant as a facetious remark. "Will they issue 'wanted posters'? Is there a bounty on our capture? Is there a breakdown of wanted people, like a price list?" As I said, "break down on" is not a valid phrase. The bounties are **broken down** into items which are placed **on a list.**

Answer (score 1):

The verb in question is '*break down*'; on is a preposition starting a prepositional phrase.

To **break *X* down** is to render it into component parts. If you break down a bill, you are listing the items on it. If you break down an analysis, it is shown in stages. If you break down a design, you are looking at component elements.

(This is not to be confused with *break down* in its intransitive sense, such as "the car broke down"; that means something, usually mechanical, stopping working)

So the question is asking if there are bounties on them, and if those bounties are listed as component elements. The final prepositional phrase "on a price list" is specifying that they would expect to see the bounty breakdowns, well, on a price list.